# Retrieving Records from Multiple Tables issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hello i am making schema for purchasing orders these orders can be ordered by certain user and then received by another user.

The issue is when UserID value in Deliveries table is null the query return no records.

UserID value is null because the order is not Delivered yet.

**Query**

```
SELECT pu.FirstName as purchase_FirstName, pu.LastName as purchase_LastName,
       du.FirstName as delivery_FirstName, du.LastName as delivery_LastName,
       po.PurchaseOrderDate,
       d.ExpectedDeliveryDate, d.ActualDeliveryDate
FROM dbo.PurchaseOrders po JOIN
     dbo.Deliveries d
     ON po.PurchaseOrderID = d.PurchaseOrderID JOIN
     dbo.Users pu
     ON po.UserID = pu.UserID JOIN
     dbo.Users du
     ON d.UserId = du.UserId;
```

**Schema**

[image]

Comment: So put a condition WHERE UserID IS NOT NULL.  Or if you want to include them you can do where userid is null.  You'll have to also change your join to a left join if you still want the record.

Comment: Will a `left join` on the `Deliveries` do the trick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you need a LEFT JOIN here. A little formatting makes this a LOT easier to read. You might take a look at this article to understand the different types of joins. http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

```
SELECT pu.FirstName as purchase_FirstName
    , pu.LastName as purchase_LastName
    , du.FirstName as delivery_FirstName
    , du.LastName as delivery_LastName
    , po.PurchaseOrderDate
    , d.ExpectedDeliveryDate
    , d.ActualDeliveryDate
FROM dbo.PurchaseOrders po 
JOIN dbo.Users pu ON po.UserID = pu.UserID 
left JOIN dbo.Deliveries d ON po.PurchaseOrderID = d.PurchaseOrderID 
left JOIN dbo.Users du ON d.UserId = du.UserId;
```